# convert base64 bytes to image asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to convert base64 bytes to an image .

This is the code i am using :

```
    Private Function Base64ToImage(ByVal base64 As String) As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
    Dim b1 As String = base64.Replace("_", "/")
    Dim b2 As String = base64.Replace("-", "+")
    Dim b64 As String = b2.Replace(" ", "+")

    Dim bb As String = b64.Substring(0, b64.Length - 3)


    Dim b() As Byte
    b = Convert.FromBase64String(b64)
    ms = New System.IO.MemoryStream(b)
    img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)

    Return img
End Function
```

This is the error i get :

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

where is the problem ??

Comment: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. You also may want to change `b2 = base64.Replace()` to `b2 = b1.Replace()`.

Comment: Why are you doing all those character replacements? And that trim?

Comment: Could you just try `b = Convert.FromBase64String(base64)` ?

Comment: You initialize `b1` with `base64.replace(...)` then `b2` with the same `base64.replace(...)`. I guess you meant: `b1 = base64.replace(...)` then `b2 = b1.replace(...)` and then `b64 = b2.replace(...)`. I wouldn't even use 3 vars and just do `base64 = base64.replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)`. Other than that: You might even consider not converting/decoding the image at all and just serve it inline as a [data-uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: @DavinTryon I am doing to trim becase the string has "= =" at tis end

Comment: @Rubik yes i tried that also gives the same error

Comment: `==` is part of base64 padding.  You need to keep that in.  A base64 string is always a length that is divisible by 4.

Comment: I don't see why you need to replace characters in the string. Does your (if any) ImageToBase64() function convert the image to Base64 properly?

Answer (score 5):

For those whe are unsure why the replacements are done: I **assume** (which is [the mother of](https://www.google.com/search?q=assumptions%20are%20the%20mother%20of%20all)...) that the string contains some [base64 variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table).

The problem is probably in this:

```
Dim b1 As String = base64.Replace("_", "/")
Dim b2 As String = base64.Replace("-", "+")
Dim b64 As String = b2.Replace(" ", "+")
```

Which should read (probably):

```
Dim b1 As String = base64.Replace("_", "/")
Dim b2 As String = b1.Replace("-", "+")
Dim b64 As String = b2.Replace(" ", "+")
```

Note the second line in above 2 snippets.

Aside from using 3 variables (or more) and wasting a lot of memory and aside the fact that these replacements **may** be unnecessary, I'd do this:

```
base64 = base64.Replace("_", "/").Replace("-", "+").Replace(" ", "+")
```

or

```
base64 = base64.Replace("_", "/")
base64 = base64.Replace("-", "+")
base64 = base64.Replace(" ", "+")
```

Which saves having (a "mid-way decoded variant" of) a base64 string in memory several times and is also safer in messing up the variables as in the first 2 snippets.

I also find it strange that both `-` and  are replaced with `+` so there's probably a mistake in there somewhere too.

Comment: Don't forget the `Dim bb As String = b64.Substring(0, b64.Length - 3)`... but maybe useless

Comment: @Rubik Agreed, I was trying to explain the princple though, not "give teh codez" :-)

Comment: Bro the problem is still there

Comment: I'm not your bro and *you* need to learn to debug. "The problem is still there" Oh, right. How are we supposed to know what you changed and how? You could've **at least** told us: "*I changed this-to-that but the problem is stil there*". Nooooo, you had to go the "bro" path. Yeah, I'm out. Bye!

Comment: I have changed to what you told me above

Comment: Did I say my answer contained a **complete** solution? How about you try to *understand* what I'm saying (instead of copy/pasting and crossing your fingers and hope it works) and apply your newly gained knowledge to your problem. I merely pointed out some mistakes (note: plural) in your code and pointed you in the right *direction* to help you solve your problem **yourself**. Bro.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a base64 string, you should not replace any chars like:

```
Dim b1 As String = base64.Replace("_", "/")
Dim b2 As String = base64.Replace("-", "+")
Dim b64 As String = b2.Replace(" ", "+")
```

This will probably make a mess of your base64 input string. Just convert the string directly to a byte[]:

```
Dim b() As Byte
b = Convert.FromBase64String(base64)
```

Comment: You make the same mistake as pasha pash does: b2 needs to be assigned **b1**.replace(...), not **base64**.replace(). This aside the fact that you could (re)use the same variable every time and that it's questionable why the replacements are done in the first place (though I assume it has to do with [some base64 variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table).

Comment: if you get a base64 string, you should not make any replacements at all. Or is the string base64 not a base64 string?

Comment: It could be a [base64 variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table).

Comment: these are comes from from a IOS app. An Image is convert to bytes using base64. And on server side i nedd these to be converted to image, so that image  can be saved to server's folder

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "data:image/png;base64,"  (or whatever is in there before the long string) before you try to convert it.